# Finding the expected total number of comparison for a Randomized Quick Sort

Tags: probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, quicksort

Let A = {2, 8, 11, 3, 12, 7, 10, 4, 15}

Want to find $E_4$.

Little unsure how to do this question. Would this be similar to finding the probability of the number of comparison 2/(j -i +1)?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit your question to make it self-contained.  What is the definition of $E_4$? of $j,i$?  And what research and reading have you done?  There's analysis of randomized quick sort in many places (including on this site, I think), so you should be able to find that, read it, and apply it to your situation.

Comment: @Dave What do you mean by $E_4$? Is it event or random variable or index of 4?